# Search results failing to display pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

i've just been learning pagination. i'm having trouble getting it to work for search results. it displays the first page correctly with the right number of links but clicking on any of the links (even on the page 1) goes to a blank page.

can somebody please tell me what i'm doing wrong:

The following code is for when the search button is clicked.

```
<div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="search">
            <div class="searchbox">
                <div id="form-container"> 
                        <div id="searchtext">
                        <form name="formSearch" method="GET" action="view_referral.php" >
                        <button class="gobtn">Search</button>
                        <input type = "text" id="s" name="searchField" size="25" placeholder="Search referrals...">
                        <input type ="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search" style="display:none;">
                        </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i have put the pagination code in a separate function:
    Here's the link to view my pagination..        https://gist.github.com/markchristian27/4a3fbc3b34e9a78ccbcc

Note: the pagination linking to other pages only fails when i attempt it with the search feature. i have tried it on a page that lists information in a table and the links work fine.

```
<div class="referentprofile"> 
                            <p>List of Referrals</p>
                            <table class="u-full-width">
                                <tr>
                                <td><strong>Lead No.<strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Referral Name</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Date Referred</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Mobile Number</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Email Address</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Call Status</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Application Status</strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php

                        $_SESSION['SESS_PAGE'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

                        // Change this during actual system run
                        if (empty($_GET['searchField'])){
                        include('../function/func_testPopulateLeads.php');
                                }
                                else {
                                    include('../function/func_testSearchByName.php');
                                    } 

                        ?>

                    </table>
                            </div>
                        <center>
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <?php 
                    include('../function/func_pagination_new.php'); 
                    ?>
                    <?=$pagination?>
                </div>
                </center>
```

pagination and links work fine in   include('../function/func_testPopulateLeads.php'); but in include('../function/func_testSearchByName.php'); **ITS NOT WORKING** Maybe It looks to me like the problem is the information in the link: http://mainpage.com/refer/view_referral.php?searchField=mark tells searchField which page to display, but it doesn't tell it what the search information was. Without that, your search page has no idea what to display.

I tried to concatenate the value of my searchField to pagination links, but still its not works fine. For example I type `mark` on my searchbox. it's link becomes like this  `http://mainpage.com/refer/view_referral.php?searchField=mark`

Then when I click the `page 2` it change to this `http://mainpage.com/refer/view_referral.php?page=2`
which is definitely retain the value of `mark` because my search page has no idea what to display when I go to next page. How to solve this issue? pls take time to read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you use links for pagination and it doesn't pass the search term as an parameter.

```
$pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";
```

This will result going to the target page with parameter "page=$next". You need to send the search term argument again each time you change a page.

You can store your search field in the view_referral.php and retrieve the value in the pagination php file.

For example:

First, saving the search value in view_referral.php:

```
$_SESSION['searchField']=$_GET['searchField'];
```

Then, in the pagination php file, retrieve the value again:

```
$pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=".$next."&searchField=".$_SESSION['searchField']."\">next</a>";
```

This should do the work for you.

Comment: Hi there @Stanley Li. Let me try and change.

Comment: Do I need to create two separate pagination for just displaying records and query results?

Comment: @newbie What do you mean by two separate pagination? You need the html file to display records and the php file to query results

Comment: I change all my `$pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";` to `$pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=".$next."&searchField=".$_SESSION['searchField']."\">next</a>";`. My search function isn't working now.

Comment: By default of loading a page, they just displaying all the records and the pagination turning to other page works fine. but when I use my search engine. my pagination isn't working properly by correct output

Comment: Show me your view_referral.php or the search logic modification

Comment: function for searching name https://gist.github.com/markchristian27/55738680fca30b42412e

Comment: Or try echo $_SESSION['searchField'] and see what's the result? do you store the search term properly?

Comment: function for pagination. I based it in your answer above :) https://gist.github.com/markchristian27/908a0bb9f2cecd571398

Comment: I try to echo it and it display the value i inputted at the search box.

Comment: I don't see where you store the search field.

Comment: view referral code bro https://gist.github.com/markchristian27/b407b9cb9af6382e2304

Comment: chck all my gist.github link. that is all concern with my search engine, pagination and page where data/record displays.

Comment: Maybe I miss the place you store the search field. Also, you need to retrieve it in your search login too. change this: $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchField']); to if(!$_GET['searchField'])$search=$_SESSION['searchField'];     else{$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchField'])}

Comment: Thanks. its now working. thanks for taking time to answer

Comment: Hi @Stanley. Have another question. Different topic :)